# How duplicate your live store on a development store and try installation on it in advance

Tags: magento2, development, duplicate

to update my theme the tutorial said
We recommend you to duplicate your live store on a development store and try installation on it in advance.

how to do this ?

and can i make something allow me to test codes before add it to alive site ?
thank you

Comment: Have you got your solution ?

Comment: No Not yet :/ i didn't

Comment: Have you tried my solution ?

Comment: yes it's working but i think there is another better way

Comment: sure i'll do this

Answer (score 3):

Try below Steps:

```
1. Create folder on server like "staging"
2. Copy all Magento related files and folder in it
3. Create a copy of database like "database_bk"
4. Create a sub-domain and point to this newly created folder
5. Change your database detail in "app/etc/env.php"
6. Change base URL and base secure URL in "core_config_data" table in your 
   staging database
7. delete  var folder
8. Staging website is ready for testing purpose
```

Hope it will work, If need any help, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a folder on the server like "staging"
2. Copy all Magento related files and folder in it
3. Create a copy of the database like "database_bk"
4. Create a sub-domain and point to this newly created folder
5. Change your database detail in "app/etc/env.php"
6. Change the base URL and base secure URL in "core_config_data" table in your 
   staging database
7. delete  var folder
8. link to ssh like puty. Run to to command

   1. php bin/magento cache:clean,
   2. php bin/magento cache:flush
9. A staging website is ready for testing purpose