# Magento 1.x - How to create a copy of my shop for testing?

Tags: magento-1.8, database, configuration

I want to create a copy of my shop so I can develope and test without destroying anything on the live.

I already copied the database and renamed it to "magento_dev", but what do I have to change in my copied magento project, to tell it to use the new database "magento_dev"?

---

I also changed `<dbname><![CDATA[magento]]></dbname>` to `<dbname><![CDATA[magento_dev]]></dbname>` in <kbd>app/etc/local.xml</kbd>.

I also edited `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` in the database table "core_config_data" to fit the new url.

- **Before:** http://localhost/projekte/magento/shop/
- **After:** http://localhost/projekte/magento/shop_dev/

I also deleted the folder `var`.

But I get "There has been an error processing your request".

[image: There has been an error processing your request]

Comment: which version of magento are you using ?

Comment: You can try https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188409/how-duplicate-your-live-store-on-a-development-store-and-try-installation-on-it/188891#188891